# How to use the Content of a List or Array as Variables

Tags: .net, vb.net

I've JUST started doodling with VB.Net 
and I need some advice for a small task I've given myself.

What I want is that the contents of a list can be used as variables.

I've made a "logon" thing" like this:

```
Sub Main()
    Dim username As String
    Dim password As Integer
    Dim nope As String = "!!!NO ACCESS!!!"
    Dim ukjent As String = "!!!UNKNOWN USER!!!"

    Console.Write("Enter your name: ")
    username = Console.ReadLine()
    Console.Write("Enter Password: ")
    password = Console.ReadLine()

    If username = "jarvis" And password = 1337 Then
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome Jarvis")
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter numerical value")

        Dim X As Decimal = Console.ReadLine()
        Dim y As Decimal = Console.ReadLine()
        Dim z As Decimal = Console.ReadLine()
        Dim i As Decimal

        i = X + y + z

        Console.WriteLine(i)
        Console.WriteLine()

    Else
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
        Console.WriteLine(nope)

    End If
    Console.ReadLine()
```

If I want to use lists where I input more "usernames" and more "passwords" how should I do this?

Could I do it like this?

```
Dim username() As String ={"User1","User2"}
Dim password() As Integer ={ 123, 321}
```

How would I recall the values in the lists? 
I know for now I'm not considering matching user1 to password 123. but that can come at a later stage, trying to build piece by piece.

Comment: Firstly, look into "concurrent arrays", which is what you're talking about there. After that, look into the `Dictionary` class in VB, which is a better option than two concurrent arrays when one array would be the natural identifiers.  Also, you could consider creating a type (class or structure) that represents a single record (`User` with `UserName` and `Password` properties) and then create a single array or collection of objects of that type.

Comment: Also note that arrays are fixed-length, so you should consider using collections rather than arrays if you want to add and/or remove items.  In that case, a `List(Of String)` and a `List(Of Integer)` would be the way to go, although a `Dictionary(Of String, Integer)` is also a collection that can grow and shrink, as would be a `List(Of User)`.

Comment: ahh.. thank you. Managed to get it working ish whith the dictionary function. 
But in a dictionary when you use:

Users.Add("User",Password) - could you give this a name. so that the key and value has to come from the same place in the dictionary ?

Comment: They already do come from the same place.  The whole point of a `Dictionary` is that the key is just that: a key.  It is what you use to access the corresponding value.  If you use `Users.Add("User", 123)` then `Users("User")` will return 123.  You can also lop through the `Dictionary` to get `KeyValuePair` objects where, in that example, the `Key` property would be "User" and the `Value` property would be 123.

Comment: yes. but if i have added:
User1, 123
User2, 321

and type inn user1 - 321 i will get a true return.

Comment: You would only get "a true return" if you wrote bad code that did that when it shouldn't. If you write good code that actually does what you want then, you know, it will do what you want.  I you're saying, without actually saying, that you want to validate a user name and password entered by the user then you simply use the user name as a key to get the corresponding password from the `Dictionary` and compare that to the password entered by the user.  They will either match or not.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is turn on Option Strict. Be sure it is on for all your coding. It will point out compile errors that will save you from runtime errors.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want your user to know if it is the username or password or both that is wrong; only that the long-in is not valid. Don't help the hacker.

TryParse takes the string that user types in. Yes, it is a string even if numbers are typed in. Look up Console.ReadLine and you will see it returns a string.

TryParse will test the string to see if it can be converted to an integer. If it succeeds it will place the value into the password variable (in this example) and if it fails a zero will be placed in password.

The .Keys method of the Dictionary returns a collection of all the keys. We check with the Contains method to see if the input username is present. If it is we use the key username to retrieve the value associated with it. If the username is not there we kick the bum out.

Finally we checked the stored password against the entered password.

All this checking is because we can't trust user to enter exactly what we expect them to enter.

```
Sub Main()
        Dim X, Y, Z As Decimal
        Dim StoredPassword As Integer 'refers to what is in the Dictionary
        Dim username As String = ""
        Dim password As Integer
        Dim nope As String = "!!!NO ACCESS!!!"
        Dim Users As New Dictionary(Of String, Integer) From {{"Mathew", 123}, {"Mark", 456}, {"Luke", 321}}
        Console.Write("Enter your name: ")
        username = Console.ReadLine()
        Console.Write("Enter Password: ")

        Integer.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), password)
        If Users.Keys.Contains(username) Then
            StoredPassword = Users(username)
        Else
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
            Console.WriteLine(nope)
            Console.ReadLine()
            End
        End If
        If StoredPassword = password Then
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green
            Console.WriteLine("Successful Login")
            Console.WriteLine($"Welcome {username}!")
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White
        Else
            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Red
            Console.WriteLine(nope)
            Console.ReadLine()
            End
        End If

        Console.WriteLine("Please enter numerical value")
        Decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), X)
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter numerical value")
        Decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), Y)
        Console.WriteLine("Please enter numerical value")
        Decimal.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), Z)
        Dim i As Decimal

        i = X + Y + Z

        Console.WriteLine($"The sum is {i}")

        Console.ReadLine() 'keeps the console window open
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Mary. 
but your code got the same problem as i do. you get "access" regardless of wich password in the dictionary you use. so if you use user "mark" and password "123"  it will stillgrant acces. instead of denying.

Comment: The Contains method is case sensitive. mark will not match Mark. This code is tested and works correctly for me. Mark or mark and password 123 will get No Access. Start a new project and copy and paste my code to see if it works for you.